# Unable to access the LUIS portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-language-understanding

We are unable to access LUIS.ai portal. A prompt appears stating error validating credentials with Active directory although I have an Azure account with the same credentials and resources created. Please find the attached screenshot and log.

```
{
    "Error": "interaction_required",
    "ErrorDescription": "AADSTS50105: The signed in user '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application '65920ba3-ab61-4a9b-9b10-505e5ce61b58'(luis.ai.live). - Trace ID: 2bbd72d5-4251-4e20-b018-5dcb6a5a2d00 - Correlation ID: 9e5d2000-7ff1-40ed-b358-797c6ef2b45c - Timestamp: 2020-01-02 05:28:01Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the Azure portal -> `Enterprise applications` -> select `Application Type` with `All applications` -> search by `luis.ai.live` -> click the app -> `Users and groups` -> Add your user account as a role (At least you need to be the `Owner` of the app to add user).

Or you can navigate to the `Properties` of the app, set the `User assignment required` to `No`, it can also solve the problem.

Also note, the two ways both need `Properties` -> `Enabled for users to sign-in` set to `Yes`.

Comment: Yes, the owner of the application has assigned  **User assignment required** to No and it worked. Thanks.