# No access to Luis Portal

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding, portal

I have a problem with sign in on Luis.ai, every time I try, the page answer with the error 404. I aprovissioned the Luis Understanding resource on my Resources Group on Azure Portal, but the answer is the same. Please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtMr0.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access the LUIS portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558728/unable-to-access-the-luis-portal)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.